# Connecting to UCSC Genome MYSQL : "Failed to connect to database"

Tags: mysql, r

I loaded the RMySQL package in R. Then tried to run the following :

```
ucscDb <- dbConnect(MySQL(),user="genome",host="genome=mysql.cse.ucsc.edu")
```

Output I get :

> Failed to connect to database: Error: Unknown MySQL Server Host 'genome=mysql.cse.ucsc.edu' (11001)

Need help bypassing this error. Is the server down or is something wrong in the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`host="genome=mysql.cse.ucsc.edu"` looks like an odd name for a host. Try

```
ucscDb <- dbConnect(MySQL(),user="genome",host="genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu")
```

its a dash rather than an equals sign: see here: https://genome.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/help/mysql.html